# How to move a specific column from a dataframe to different target

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

I have a dataframe and I want to move a specific column to a different target (other columns from  dataframe to different target)

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
      'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to move name to different target and age to different target in s3.

Comment: what do you mean moving to a different target ? To a new collumn ?

Comment: To differents buckets in s3

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
import boto3
from io import StringIO  

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
def Put_in_S3(df, bucket_name, FileName):  
    csv_buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
    s3_client.put_object(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket_name, Key=FileName)
```

For your use case, in order to save your dataframes seperately in different buckets as per your request above, please try the following:

```
Put_in_S3(df=df[["Name"]],Bucket_name='my_bucket_name1', FileName='Name.csv')
Put_in_S3(df=df[["Age"]],Bucket_name='my_bucket_name2', FileName='Age.csv')
```